Simplest way to hide a page from Streamlit sidebar
I have two pages, page1,py and page2.py in my pages folder. page1.py calls page2.py, so I want to hide page2.py from the sidebar/side navigation. What is the simplest way to do this?

There’s st_pages, but that doesn’t work in a docker container for some reason
There are multiple posts on hiding the entire sidebar and recreating it in a custom way, but these are brittle. Sometimes both sidebars show up.
I’ve tried mucking around with the CSS + Javascript to hide a single element, but no success so far.

Happy to share more details on my attempts, but there ought to be a very simple way to hide a page. Or if I can move page2.py to a subfolder in page and then have page1.py call it via st.switch_page(“pages/subpages/page2.py”) that would work too, but seems like you can only switch_page to whatever is within the pages folder.

In a multipage app, you can hide the side bar by the following procedure.

Create a .streamlit folder under your app main folder.



The hide_sidebar folder is your main app folder.
The app.py is the main streamlit file.


Under the .streamlit folder create a config.toml file and the content of this file is this.

[client]
showSidebarNavigation = false



Rerun streamlit to see its effect.

How to show a page in a sidebar
Now if you want to show a single page in the sidebar, for example the basketball page, you can create a page link widget and show it in the sidebar.
app.py
import streamlit as st


st.header('Home')

# Sidebar navigation
st.sidebar.page_link('app.py', label='Home')
st.sidebar.page_link('pages/basketball.py', label='Basketball')

basketball.py
import streamlit as st


st.header('Basketball')

# Sidebar navigation
st.sidebar.page_link('app.py', label='Home')
st.sidebar.page_link('pages/basketball.py', label='Basketball')


Sample output

The soccer page is not shown.

Thank you. Very well explained. Also, I had to put this all in a function so I can call this with every page.

Do whatever you want, optimize it etc. but test it if it works.

I needed the same feature and I noticed that by creating a page with an empty space as a title, it does the trick:
visible_page = st.Page("page_folder/visible.py", title="My visible page")
invisible_page = st.Page("page_folder/invisible.py", title=" ")

page = st.navigation([visible_page, invisible_page])
page.run()

You can navigate to the invisible page from the visible page by calling     st.switch_page("page_folder/invisible.py")
It would be great for streamlit to support this feature in st.Page or st.navigation.
